# How to parse html in a textarea input and addClass to td elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

My problem is this: I'm submitting a form with a textarea input, which contains an HTML table in the content with specific values in the TD elements which I am trying to parse and add a class to the TD based on that value; then save that back to the form before being sent to the server.

The table looks something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>r</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>y</td>
  <td>n</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here's the JS I have right now:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
  var table = $('#mytextarea').val();

  $('td', table).each(function() {
    var td = $(this);
    switch(td.text()) {
      case 'r':
        td.addClass('red');
        break
      case 'y':
        td.addClass('yellow');
        break
    }
    table = td.wrap('table').parent().html();
  });
});
```

So essentially I just want to parse HTML inside of a string and add classes to the elements, then save back to the string, if that makes sense.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z265d/

I think I'm close but not quite there yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrapped a div around your table, and changed the `wrap` to `closest`, which will get the table, then its parent (div), and get its html.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z265d/3/

```
var table = '<div><table><tr><td>r</td><td>y</td></tr><tr><td>g</td><td>b</td></tr></table></div>';

$('td', table).each(function() {
  var td = $(this);
  switch(td.text()) {
    case 'r':
      td.addClass('red');
      break;
    case 'y':
      td.addClass('yellow');
      break;
    case 'b':
      td.addClass('blue');   
      break;
    case 'g':
      td.addClass('green');   
      break;          
  }
  table = td.closest('table').parent().html();
});

$('#output').text(table);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap value of the `mytextarea` textarea into jQuery object:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var table = $($('#mytextarea').val());
    var styles = {
        "r": "red",
        "g": "green",
        "y": "yellow",
        "b": "blue"
    };

    $('td', table).each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (styles[text]) {
            $(this).addClass(styles[text]);
        }
    });

    $('#mytextarea').val(table.html());
});​
```

Fiddler Link: http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/LmhJF/

Comment: This also worked, just needs a <div> wrapper around the table to get the table tags back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe first wrap the text with jquery and then convert it back to text.

```
var table = $('<table><tr><td>r</td><td>y</td></tr><tr><td>g</td><td>b</td></tr></table>');

$('td', table).each(function() {
  var td = $(this);
  switch(td.text()) {
    case 'r':
      td.addClass('red');
      break;
    case 'y':
      td.addClass('yellow');
      break;
    case 'b':
      td.addClass('blue');   
      break;
    case 'g':
      td.addClass('green');   
      break;          
  }
  table = td.wrap('table').parent().html();
});

$('#output').text(table);
​
```

Please find below the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/Z265d/4/)

Hope this helps